# How do big companies like github queue their emails

Tags: laravel, email, queue, task-queue, multiple-processes

I have recently been working on a company where we were sending emails to users, and we had a queue named email, which was specifically used to queue emails in the system. But this was taking too long to send all the messages, especially when the users were over 5000. So I was wondering how do big companies do this, and the way their email messages are always timely, it almost takes no time. Can somebody provide me with some insight please.

I am using laravel framework to do the work.

Comment: Are you using your own mail server, or a 3rd party? Using a 3rd party mail service can mean faster throughput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with queue because it seems you are sending bulk email.

If you are using your own Mail server it will depends on your **IP/Domain reputation and limit** (each provider (ex: Gmail, Outlook, ..) has its limit for new IP's).

You have to **warm up your IP** on each provider so they can trust you (not to mention you have to setup correct **DNS (DKIM, DMARC, SPF, ...)**).

If you are using 3rd-party(**mailchamp, sendgrid,...**) so it will depend on their limit (by hour|day|month) you have just to send the body and list of emails and they will do the rest.

This comment will be updated after you provide more info !